# What are the norms for releasing the same package under multiple names on PyPI?

Tags: python, packaging, pypi, python-packaging

Suppose I've uploaded a package called `foobar` to PyPI. Because the package is a Django module, I'd also like to publish it as `django-foobar`.

What is the general consensus towards releasing the same package under multiple names? Is it allowed or forbidden? Encouraged or discouraged?

(To prevent this question from appearing or becoming too opinion-based, I'm hoping someone can point me to some specific, published norms or obvious precedents. Thank you!)

Answer (score 0):

The published recommendations are in [PEP-0423](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0423), but the status of that document is 'deferred' (not 'rejected', but not 'approved' either). That is, they don't have much official standing, but they are generally good recommendations nonetheless.

Specifically, the [Use a single name](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0423/#use-a-single-name) recommendation seems relevant. If your code works as a standalone package, then `foobar` (i.e., its own name) would be appropriate. If it is dependent on Django, then `django-foobar` is more [meaningful](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0423/#pick-meaningful-names). Of course, if Django has published recommendations for packaging modules, then [those should be followed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0423/#conventions-for-communities-or-related-projects).

Whichever way you choose, stick to one. It is confusing to have the same code under two project names (not to mention the headaches of having to maintain and push updates to both projects with each release).